# Understanding the scope of Content Security Policy frame-ancestors

Tags: html, iframe, content-security-policy

So far, my webservers always set the `X-Frame-Options "sameorigin"` header and I didn't have any problem. However, now I needed to use an iframe at other server, but to my surprise, `allow-from` is deprecated by Chrome and Safari, so can't use `X-Frame-Options`.

So, I'm switching my headers to CSP, but I'm having some issues.

Assume two servers, XA (192.168.1.1) and XB (192.168.1.2). XA is serving a page with some charts and XB is serving a page with an iframe to one of those charts.

In XA I use the following header: `Header set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self' 192.168.1.1"`. However, when I visit the XB's site, the iframe's content is not loaded because it violates the CSP policy.

So, I have two questions:

1) In which direction does the policy work?? XA --> XB or XA <-- XB? In other words, is the 192.168.1.1 correct or should I use 192.168.1.2 instead? Tried both and didn't work, but just to know which is the right one.

2) What may be the reason to get the policy violation error?

For testing purposes, both XA and XB are just serving simple HTML, nothing fancy.

XA

```
<html>
<body>
    lalala
</body>
</html>
```

XB

```
<html>
<body>
    <iframe src="http://192.168.1.1"/>
</body>
</html>
```

The browser's console error when I visit XB: `Refused to display 'http://192.168.1.1/' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' http://192.168.1.1".`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind... just found the what's causing the problem.

As for 1) the policy needs to point to 192.168.1.2.

About 2) it wasn't working because XB was my laptop, I was pointing the browser to localhost. After change the Apache to run on 192.168.1.2 instead of 127.0.0.1, it worked.